# Is it possible to make a app logo icon exceed the height of the Actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-icons

My visual designer just handed me a mockup with an oversized app logo icon in the Actionbar. I have never seen accomplished in an Android app. Is it possible, and if so, where is the height of the icon specified?

I am shooting for something that looks like the example on the right.

[image: Mock up of oversized Actionbar icon]

Comment: Not definite, but I'm thinking no with the default ActionBar classes. You'll have to roll your own custom one. I wouldn't recommend this really though. I think it'd lead to an inconsistent experience with other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible but you can make it with a little tip

If your dessigner divide the icon in two parts, in this case, the top of the Droid and the legs of the droid and you add this legs to the Activity layout with a ImageView/View you can simulate the effect of the bigger icon.

The unique problem is the icon padding but i think you can set to 0. Perhaps its more easy if you use the ActionBar Sherlock library and change the code (its open source)
ActionBar Sherlock and the ActionBar native are equals